# intellij plugin develop book

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea

I want to develop a plugin for intellij , but I find that the resource about that is very little,and there isn't a book about it ,so anyone know about this resource or book ? thank you very much

Comment: a simple demo is best way to start: https://github.com/whunmr/emacsIDEAs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This page should help you out:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/open_api_plugin_manager.html

Essentially you'll need to learn the Open API, which isn't too difficult, and you can visit several of the plugin examples that exist out there to see how others are doing things.  Some plugins with source:

- https://github.com/kinabalu/mysticpaste/tree/master/idea-plugin
- http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/10/check-out-more-than-200-open-source-plugins/ (lots of plugin example code here)

Comment: Also **Open API and Plugin Development Forums** at http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea/open_api_and_plugin_development?view=discussions

Comment: Also **Live Coding a Plugin From Scratch** blog entries: [part 1](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/12/webinar-recording-live-coding-a-plugin-from-scratch/) and [part 2](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/01/live-coding-a-plugin-from-scratch-webinar-part-2/)

Comment: thanks, so by now there is not a book about plugin development